# How do I display a UIImage at a specific place on the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to get a UIImage to display at a certain spot on the screen.  I've tried the initWithFrame in the code below, but it still displays at the top left corner.  What should I do instead?

```
UIImage *headImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"head"];
UIImageView *headView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:headImage] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 400.0, 500.0)];
[self.view addSubview:headView];
```

Comment: Do you want the image view to have a specific size or do you want the image view's size to match the size of the image?

Comment: you have two inits nested - that won't work.  see peter foti's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following: set the frame **after** you create the image view

```
UIImage *headImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"head"];
UIImageView *headView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:headImage];
headView.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 400.0, 500.0);
[self.view addSubview:headView];
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `init` twice. Change your code to:

```
UIImage *headImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"head"];
UIImageView *headView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 400.0, 500.0)];
headView.image = headImage;
[self.view addSubview:headView];
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great if you want the image view to have a specific size. But if you want the image view's size to match the image's size as well as position the image view in a specific location then you should do:

```
UIImage *headImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"head"];
UIImageView *headView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:headImage] 
CGRect frame = headView.bounds;
frame.origin.x = 200;
frame.origin.y = 400;
headView.frame = frame;
[self.view addSubview:headView];
```

This code has the benefit of working even if you change the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change image size, then you can simple use `setCenter` method to move image on screen.

```
UIImage *headImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"head"];
UIImageView *headView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:headImage];
[headView setCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100)]; // x, y
[self.view addSubview:headView];
```